# php regex not working in php [preg_replace}

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to remove the following html but my regex isn't working

```
<div class="vmargin"><div><iframe src="/test.php?u=N0Bhlant98C6MRj0D44HwJMuf5TdA%2F24oG9hQ2qqX6IR2IruUxVrrhLR4EpHQDvGtuHH4%2BLgJMBG6L5%2BTs6t6FfgCbo%3D&amp;b=5&amp;f=frame" style="width:718px;height:438px;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;" __idm_frm__="100"></iframe></div><div><a href="" class="report_video" data-video-id="732253" title="Report Video">Video Broken?</a></div></div>
```

I tried the following regex

```
preg_replace("@<div class=\"vmargin\".*?<\\/div>.*?<\\/div><\\/div>@s",'', $input);
```

What's wrong with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `\\` because in your closing divs, there are no `\` character. Try this:

```
<div class=\"vmargin\".*?<\/div>.*?<\/div><\/div>
```

So:

```
$string = '<div class="vmargin"><div><iframe src="/test.php?u=N0Bhlant98C6MRj0D44HwJMuf5TdA%2F24oG9hQ2qqX6IR2IruUxVrrhLR4EpHQDvGtuHH4%2BLgJMBG6L5%2BTs6t6FfgCbo%3D&amp;b=5&amp;f=frame" style="width:718px;height:438px;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;" __idm_frm__="100"></iframe></div><div><a href="" class="report_video" data-video-id="732253" title="Report Video">Video Broken?</a></div></div>';
$input = preg_replace("@<div class=\"vmargin\".*?<\/div>.*?<\/div><\/div>@s", '', $string);
var_dump($input);
```

Output: `string '' (length=0)`

Comment: That was not the problem. That works with your solution too, after i checked, and work with this also: `@<div class=\"vmargin\".*?</div>.*?</div></div>@s` without any escaping (at the divs).

Comment: my regex didn't work but yours did.Can you explain why mine don't work since you say `\\` was not the problem

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not technically an answer, but to make the result readable (code formatting required)

Works for me:

```
<?php

$input = '<div class="vmargin"><div><iframe src="/test.php?u=N0Bhlant98C6MRj0D44HwJMuf5TdA%2F24oG9hQ2qqX6IR2IruUxVrrhLR4EpHQDvGtuHH4%2BLgJMBG6L5%2BTs6t6FfgCbo%3D&amp;b=5&amp;f=frame" style="width:718px;height:438px;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;" __idm_frm__="100"></iframe></div><div><a href="" class="report_video" data-video-id="732253" title="Report Video">Video Broken?</a></div></div>';

echo( "!".preg_replace("@<div class=\"vmargin\".*?<\\/div>.*?<\\/div><\\/div>@s",'', $input) .'!' );
```

Output:

```
C:\test>php test.php
!!
```

Moving to `'` quoted strings and removing the escaping makes it easier to read though

```
$input = '<div class="vmargin"><div><iframe src="/test.php?u=N0Bhlant98C6MRj0D44HwJMuf5TdA%2F24oG9hQ2qqX6IR2IruUxVrrhLR4EpHQDvGtuHH4%2BLgJMBG6L5%2BTs6t6FfgCbo%3D&amp;b=5&amp;f=frame" style="width:718px;height:438px;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;" __idm_frm__="100"></iframe></div><div><a href="" class="report_video" data-video-id="732253" title="Report Video">Video Broken?</a></div></div>';

echo( '!'.preg_replace('@<div class="vmargin".*?</div>.*?</div></div>@s','', $input) .'!' );
```

Same output